# What did pangolin scales evolve from?

Tags: evolution, zoology, scales

Were they developed anew or a heritage from fish?

Answer (score 7):

Pangolin scales are certainly not retained from fish. Pangolins are within the clade [Pholidota](http://tolweb.org/Pholidota/15954) ([Tree of Life page for Eutheria](http://tolweb.org/Eutheria/15997)) and their nearest relatives are anteaters, sloths, and armadillos.

According to the [University of California Museum of Paleontology](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/mammal/eutheria/pholidota.html), similarities between pangolin and armadillos are the results of convergent evolution. So the pangolin scales are a new feature that arose somewhere on the lineage leading to pangolins.

Comment: were they developed from hair or from skin folds?

Comment: They are keratinous scales, like hair and claws/nails. I'd suspect similar development to nails, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Their closest relatives are carnivores, not anteaters, sloths, and armadillos.  See DOI: 10.1186/1471-2148-6-93.